# Angular 6 forkJoin not returning the data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to make multiple request by using for loop and then using forkJoin to get all the data at once.

To get data, I have created one function in my service component and then inside for loop after calling that function I am subscribing it and then pushing the data into temporary variable. And after that when for loop is completed I am expecting forkJoin to subscribe and return the value.

Code:

```
const observables = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.originalData.length; i++) {
       this.dashboardService.getDetails(this.id1[i], this.id2[i]).subscribe(data => {
           observables.push(data);
       });
}
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(dataGroup => {
    console.log(dataGroup);
});
```

If I check my network in inspect element then I can see that it is requesting those urls and the response is of 200 status but in console I don't see any error but at the same time there is no output from forkJoin subscribe.
I am new to this so may be I am not understanding it correctly how to use forkJoin.

Also I am using rxjs": "^6.0.0",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create array of observables and then provide those observables to `forkJoin`:

```
const observables = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.originalData.length; i++) {
      observables.push( this.dashboardService.getDetails(this.id1[i], this.id2[i])
       };

forkJoin(...observables).subscribe(dataGroup => {
    console.log(dataGroup);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution. So I need not to subscribe at for loop, will later accept it

Comment: @sive636, you needn't the spread operator, NOT forkJoin(...observables), just forkJoin(observables)

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, you are correct. forkJoin accepts individual arguments as well as arrays.

Comment: @siva636, observables is an array already, if you write forkJoin(...observables) you're copying the array and make the forkJoin, it's not necessary